# Creating a new Maven Project

Tags: maven, m2e, spring-tools-4

So I am creating a new Maven project in Spring Tool Suite 4. However, after creating the project I am getting the following.

[image: Image 1]

and

[image: Image 2]

Why is this happening? How to fix it?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: [maven-resources-plugin:2.6](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.maven.plugins%20AND%20a:maven-resources-plugin&core=gav) and [maven-filtering:1.1](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.maven.shared%20AND%20a:maven-filtering&core=gav) are almost 7 years old. What if you try it with a newer (external) Maven version in your Eclipse?

Comment: @GeroldBroser I really had no idea that they were too old. I downloaded the Spring Suite 4. They should have had the updated Maven version, shouldn't they? Is there any way to update the maven version?